# Add Nofollow Attribute To Whole Article Directory?

Tags: directory, nofollow

I have a article directory, which is created on article setup script. Website name is pakgirl.net. I want to make all of its links in articles nofollow to increase my website's PR. anyone help me plzz  :(  as i m not a developer. just know that there are files in my hosting.

Answer (score 3):

Your free article directory is based on Wordpress and using free article directory theme.

I searched online for:
globally adding rel=nofollow to wp article directory

and here is a list WP plugins that may help you
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tags/nofollow

Other then that, you could export, correct it offline, import groups of articles at a time

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -i 's#<a href#<a rel="nofollow" href#' yourpage.php
```

this will overwrite file or "edit in place"

do this first as a dry run

```
find yourDirectory/ \( -name "*.html" -o -name "*.php" \) | xargs sed 's#<a href#<a rel="nofollow" href#' <dryrun.txt
```